# Using a variable inside Sed expression for the command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to change few things in a file based on line numbers.

```
sed -n -i "$command|ABC|XYZ" ".$file_name"
```

The command variable is going to take the values such as 200s,311s and so on

I'm getting "sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command"

What could be going wrong?

Comment: a missing `|` after `XYZ` ?

Comment: Thanks @oliv ! Its working now with your change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this;

```
sed -i "$command|ABC|XYZ|" ".$file_name"
```

you need to insert `|` after XYZ and delete `-n` option.

Comment: Why change `".$file_name"` for  `${file_name}` ? The OP may want to apply command on hidden file and filename should be quoted.

Comment: Thanks muzido and Kenavoz. It started working after the suggested change